# Questions about manipulation of "mysql_fetch_array" result

Tags: php

By default mysql_fetch_array returns numeric and associative array togeather. This function is useful for reading, while you can get values

either by statement : 
echo arr[1]; //circle 
or 
echo arr["shape"]; //circle

I am new to PHP and I run into the troubles when I wanted to change the values of that fetched array:
arr[1] = square;

I supposed that arr["shape"] will be 'square' too, but I was wrong. arr["shape"] still remains 'circle'.
Obviously you have to change both values to 'circle'.

Moreover: I wrote a funcion which should return changed shape array, (which is 2D array). I got different outcomes, if I used the first or

the second line of code.

```
function ChangeShape($arr)
        {

            for ($i=0; $i<$count($arr); $i++)
            {
         1.    $arr[$i]["shape"] = 'square'; // fail to return changed $arr - it is (probably) reference to number counterpart

         2.    $arr[$i][2] = 'square';       // this WILL return changed $arr
            }
            }
            return $arr;
        }
```

My questions:
1. is there any technique in PHP by which I can change both values at once?
2. in my app I use assoc nicknames to access array values. But when it is not possible to change numeric alias at the same time, what is

the easiest way to do it?

thank for reading this to the end... hope you answer.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This sounds a bit complicated. Why do you need both the indexed and the associative version present in the first place? What one would usually do is fetch the results from the record - *either* the numerically indexed or the associative indexed ones - into another variable, and manipulate things there.

Comment: @Pekka> There are some places, where i use numerical representations and sometimes more friendly assoc (strings). I was used in other programming languages to use one or another option interchargebly. I am in learning process in PHP. But it is not bad idea you just said.

Comment: I happen to think using numerical representation is a terrible idea in most cases, because if you make a small change to your query you'll likely break all sorts of things.  I see even less of a reason to be inconsistent.  Is there a good reason you use numeric values in some places and associative in others?

Comment: I do not have the strong reason... I wondered, if it is possible to address values by both ways and modify them also by both ways. At least I expected that PHP do it for me...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the data in a simple array once you grab it, you can always just simplify it by putting it in a few array:

```
 $query = "SELECT * from myTable";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 $newArray = array();

 $i=0; 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   array_push(  $newArray, $row[$i]['name'] );
 }
 print_r($newArray);
 $newArray[4] = "some other value than what came from the db";
 print_r($newArray);
```

It doesn't seem super clear why your data is coming back as complicated as it seems to be, but this might help clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to fetch numeric index?  At least based on what you've posted it seems like you just want to call mysql_fetch_assoc to get an array with just the associative version.

The "aliases" in the array returned by mysql_fetch_array aren't really aliases... it just inserts it twice into the result array, once with the numeric index and once with the name of the column.  The only way to change them both is to assign them both the desired value.

Comment: > so that's what I am afraid to be happened. I used debugger to view what is going on, and it seemed, that the second "alias" value is given by reference to that numeric one. Changing that reference changed nothing on the end, but changing numeric changed returned table...

Answer (score 0):

See this example and maybe it will make sense why its not working.  Its not a reference or it would be working.  If you had to have this functionality, you could build your array like this:

```
<?

$a='dog';
$b='cat';

$arr=array ('a' => &$a, 1 => &$a,'b' => &$b,'2' => &$b );

print_r($arr);

$a='horse';

print_r($arr);

$arr[1]='cow';

print_r($arr);
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [a] => dog
    [1] => dog
    [b] => cat
    [2] => cat
)

Array
(
    [a] => horse
    [1] => horse
    [b] => cat
    [2] => cat
)
Array
(
    [a] => cow
    [1] => cow
    [b] => cat
    [2] => cat
)
```

Comment: It makes sense... understand. I think I have to simplify my work... thanx